# Layout element: one on top of the other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I would like to create a **ad banner** which shows at the **bottom** of the screen, and the page of the screen is **scrollable** except the banner. Banner stay at bottom constantly.

So, I need a `<ScrollView>` element, and I need a `<LinearLayout>` element positioned on top of the `<ScrollView>`. and located at the **bottom** of the screen.

How can I implement the layout for ad banner in Android ??? (I am developing **Android 2.1 API 7** app) , can someone give me some hints??

*********UPDATE***************

I figured out to use `<FrameLayout>` , but still interested to hear other opinions.

Comment: FrameLayout is the easiest way. The other answers below are way too complex.

Answer (score 1):

Another option(and much simpler i guess) you have is to use this type of layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView>
       //here is the scroll
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
      // here is the ad
    </LinearLayout> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see some ways to do this.

1 Simple use `Activity.addContentView()` to add an additional content view to the activity.

- your ad **not depend** from main layout

2 Use `android:layout_alignParentBottom` as suggest **slukian**.

- you ad **depend** from main layout

3 Create your own View class which contain ad. In method onDraw() call: `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, posX, posY, null);`. Where posX, posY - is absolute positions. Then add your View to main layout as in way1.